# Sending jms message to remote queue in grails

Tags: grails, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I'm novice to Jms with grails. I have searched a lot for this issue but didn't find the relevant help from the internet. I want to create a functionality in which I need to send a message to the queue which is located on the remote server. I have the same functionality working on weblogic server with ejb. I need to mimic the same functionality here using grails. So can you please help me that how can I use grails jms plugin to send a message to remote queue.

My ejb config file is like this.

```
<ServerStart Arguments="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dj2.appserver=weblogic" Name="myserver"
PasswordEncrypted="{3DES}2FADEdsewdasg23dfs1rw==" sername="user123"/>
<JMSJDBCStore ConnectionPool="JMS-JDBCPOOL" Name="JMS JDBC" PrefixName="XYZ"/>
<JMSServer Name="MyJMS Server" Store="JMS JDBC" Targets="myserver">
    <JMSQueue CreationTime="1096677212825" ExpirationPolicy="Log"
        JNDIName="jms/import_users" Name="Import_user"/>
    <JMSQueue CreationTime="1174946938851"
        JNDIName="jms/update_users" Name="update_user"/>
</JMSServer>
<JMSConnectionFactory JNDIName="jms/qcf" Name="qcf"
    Targets="myserver" XAConnectionFactoryEnabled="true"/>
<ForeignJMSServer ConnectionURL="t3://IP_ADDRESS:PORT"
    JNDIProperties="" Name="MyForeign JMSServer" Targets="myserver">
    <ForeignJMSDestination LocalJNDIName="jms/update_users"
        Name="MyForeign JMSDestination" RemoteJNDIName="jms/update_users"/>
</ForeignJMSServer>
```

and web.xml is

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <description>import user reference</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>jms/import_users</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.jms.Queue</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>

<resource-env-ref>
    <description>update user reference</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>jms/update_users</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.jms.Queue</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>

<resource-ref>
    <description>jms reference</description>
    <res-ref-name>jms/qcf</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

So I want to send a message to the queue named "update_users". How can i send it in grails using jms and ActiveMQ plugin. How to configure config.groovy using REMOTE_IP:PORT and which protocol should be used instead of weblogic t3 protocol. Please answer the step by step procedure. Thanks in advance.